# d3 scale, put ticks every Nth day evenly spaced

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a tick on my chart every Nth day, with the number of days configurable. If the user chooses "30 days", then the scale should show a tick every 30 days.

To do so, what I've tried is to pass an interval with `d3.timeDay`. The issue is that D3 docs tell me [the dates are not uniformly spaced](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_every). Furthermore, it doens't work above 30 days.

```
d3.timeDay.every(30).range(new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 2, 1));
// returns
[
  2015-01-01,
  2015-01-31,
  2015-02-01,
]
```

How can I get uniformly spaced dates (and ticks?)

```js
    const dom = [new Date(2019, 1, 1), new Date(2020, 1, 1)]

    const width = 600
    const height = 200
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(dom)
      .range([0, width])

    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .append("g")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(30))
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y")))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it with `d3.count()`, filtering every date that comes and checking the spacing against the first date. Feel free to answer if there's a better solution.

```js
    const dom = [new Date(2019, 1, 1), new Date(2020, 1, 1)]

    const width = 600
    const height = 200
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(dom)
      .range([0, width])

    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
      .append("g")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d => d3.timeDay.count(dom[0], d) % 30 === 0))
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y")))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```